# Need some help ordering a Linq result

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have some Linq code, that works fine. It retrieves a list of board posts ordered by the most recent.

The catch here is the *order by* ... it orders by the most recent COMMENTS. So if a board post just got a comment, then it will be up the top of the list (ie. most recent).

kewl ... but what about new board posts that just got created? They are listed down the bottom, because they have NO comments :( It's like i want to say "*order by most recent comments .. but if u have no comment, then its by your board post create date)*".

here's my linq...

```
boardPostList = (from bp in db.tblBoardPosts.Where(whereClause)
    orderby (from bc in bp.tblBoardComments
    orderby bc.DateModified descending
    select bc.DateModified).First() descending
    select bp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, numberOfResults);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't update a field in `tblBoardPosts` whenever a comment is posted to it? Keep the "posted or last comment" date, then you've got a *much* simpler query, and one which doesn't need to scan every comment in the system to work out what to do.

Having said that, this query *might* work, if your `DateModified` field is nullable:

```
boardPostList = (from bp in db.tblBoardPosts.Where(whereClause)
    orderby ((from bc in bp.tblBoardComments
    orderby bc.DateModified descending
    select bc.DateModified).FirstOrDefault() ?? bp.DateModified) descending
    select bp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, numberOfResults);
```

If it's just a straight `DateTime` column, the result of `FirstOrDefault` is still a `DateTime` which would be non-nullable... You could try:

```
boardPostList = (from bp in db.tblBoardPosts.Where(whereClause)
    let lastComment = bp.tblBoardComments
                        .OrderByDescending(bc => bc.DateModified)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
    let lastModified = (lastComment == null 
                        ? bp.DateModified 
                        : lastComment.DateModified) 
    orderby lastModified descending
    select bp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, numberOfResults);
```

It's pretty hideous though, and may not translate into SQL properly. I would certainly try to change to a scheme where the post itself keeps track of it.

Comment: Heya Jon :) heh .. i tried the first suggestion while i was waiting for some answers, but it wouldn't compile because the DateTime is not null, as u correctly pointed out. I had no idea how to get to the second suggestion, u made... which works. So thanks :) (BTW, schema change is now pencilled in, btw. Gotta do it right...)

Comment: That works? I'm somewhat surprised, to be honest. I guess the LINQ to SQL query translator is pretty smart :)